# Is it acceptable to assign a "Read from file" function to a variable?

Tags: c++, function

So i have FRead function that reads data from file. I need to finish the program if the function returns error codes. Is it acceptable to do it like this:

```
string check=FRead(vec);
```

And then put some if statements that finish the program if check has certain values.

It is the only instance in program when i call the function and obviously i can't call it many times. It seems to work alright, but i'm not quite sure if it is the right way. So is there a proper way to do what i'm trying to do?

And i also have the KRead function reading input from keyboard, which too returns an error code if things go wrong. And i call it like this

```
if(KRead=='ERROR')
   return 1
```

Is it okay to do so?

Comment: Why use strings rather than error codes? You could use an `enum`, for example. However, I only recommend using error codes if it's safe for the client to ignore the error. If something exceptional happens that `FRead` can't handle itself and must be handled by the client, you should throw an exception.

Comment: Actually i am using error codes, just wanted to illustrate what i'm trying to do better

Comment: Wait, so what's your question? I thought you were asking if it was okay to use strings to report errors.

Comment: Is the FRead() function something you created yourself? If so it's cleaner to use an `enum` for your error codes. When you call your function you can use a `switch` to assign different action on your error codes. http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/control/

Comment: Eh, i'm sorry. I misunderstood you. I don't use the error codes you mentioned. The functions return integers actually. I haven't learned enum yet. My question is if it is an acceptable function call.

Comment: The question isn't about what data types to use for error codes, it's about whether or not returning the error code into a variable and then checking the variable is acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always better to use error codes or exceptions. The choice between both depends on the implementation. I made a few example applications that explain in general what string errors, error codes and exceptions are.

### String errors

This will work but it's ugly, also you don't know what errors there are defined without disecting the `GenerateError()` function).

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Example
{
public:
    std::string GenerateError(bool error)
    {
        if (error)
        {
            return "ERROR";
        }
        return "OK";
    };
};


int main() 
{
    Example example;

    if ("ERROR" == example.GenerateError(true))
    {
        return 1; // failure
    }
    return 0; // success
}
```

### Error Codes

With an `enum` you specify which error codes are available (in this case `Ok`, `Error` and `Error2`). This makes the code easier to understand and it will save you from mistakes. With enums you can also make use of `switch`.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

enum ErrorCodes
{
    Ok = 0,
    Error,
    Error2
    //...
};

class Example
{
public:    
    ErrorCodes GenerateError(bool error)
    {
        if (error)
        {
            return ErrorCodes::Error;
        }
        return ErrorCodes::Ok;
    };
};


int main() 
{
    Example example;

    // Regular if statement
    if (ErrorCodes::Ok == example.GenerateError(true))
    {
        return 1; // failure
    }
    else
    {
        return 0; // success
    }

    // switch statement
    switch (example.GenerateError(true))
    {
    case Error:
    case Error2:
        return 1; // failure
        break;
    case Ok:
        return 0; // success
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

### Exceptions

Exceptions are a bit more complex but are definitely worth it to check out. Use exceptions when you want to obligate the user of the function to do something with the error. When the function does not require an action on an error it's probably better to use error codes.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class CustomException :public std::exception{
public:
    CustomException(const std::string m) :strMessage(m){}
    ~CustomException(void);
    const char* what(){ return strMessage.c_str(); }
private:
    std::string strMessage;
};

class Example
{
public:

    void GenerateError(bool error)
    {
        if (error)
        {
            throw CustomException("Critical error");
        }
        return;
    };
};


int main() 
{
    Example example;

    try
    {
        example.GenerateError(true);
    }
    catch (CustomException ce)
    {
        std::cerr << ce.what() << std::endl;
        return 1; // failure
    }
    return 0; // success
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A good way to handle error conditions in C++ is to have your function throw exceptions if something goes wrong. You can then check for exceptions when you call it. See http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/exceptions/.

Answer (score 0):

This is perfectly fine.  Like others have said though, you can use error codes instead of strings.